# Fixed element having fixed child, absolute element having absolute child

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

While trying to wrap my head around fixed and absolute positions, I came across this peculiar situation which I quite don't understand. The fixed child despite having the same size as absolute child still differ in size? Why does that happen? Both fixed parent and Absolute parent are same in size as well.

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="maincontainer w-full h-screen">
      <div className=" fixexparent fixed w-[50%] h-[50%] bg-emerald-200 right-0 bottom-0">
        <div className=" fixedchild fixed w-[20%] h-[20%]  bg-yellow-200  "></div>
      </div>
      <div className="child absolute bg-blue-200 w-[50%] h-[50%]">
        <div className="anotherchild absolute bg-rose-200 w-[20%] h-[20%] bottom-0 right-0 "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App
```

Comment: This is because absolute positioned elements take width and height relative to it's parent. So 20% in anotherchild is actually 20% of child's width.

Comment: That I understand, but in the fixedparent and fixedchild, the fixedchild is positioned relative to the fixed parent(I've it in my browser and looking at it right now). So if the fixedchild is also positioned relative to fixedparent, shouldn't it take the same dimensions as anotherchild?(since both are relative to their parents who share the same dimensions)?

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms,

**fixed**: is positioned relative to the viewport.

**absolute**: is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor element.

Explaination:

When the page is scrolled, a fixed element remains in place relative to the viewport. As the viewport size may be different from the size of its fixed parent, the fixed child element with `20%` `width` and `height` is related to that size.

Whereas the absolute child element in this instance is positioned in relative to its absolute parent element, which is `50%` larger than the main container. As a result, the size of the absolute child element, which is `20%` wider and taller than the main container, is relative to the size of its absolute parent element.